# jQuery resizable: When resizing element in scrollable container cursor looses the handle

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I've been trying to using jQuery resizable to resize an element in a container that is scrollable. I need to be able to make the element larger than what fits in the viewport, so therefor the page must scroll during the resize. How do I do that?

Note that the element is also draggable but not by the same handle (I'm not sure if that will affect the solution?)
When I've tried I get an issue with the handle which doesn't follow the mouse when I scroll the page.

First when I resized the element and drags the mouse down, the page didn't scroll. so therefor I've added the following (which might not be correct) on the resize event of the resizable element to scroll when the handle gets close to the upper or lower border:

```
    resize: (event, ui) => {
        var container = $(".container");
        var pos = ui.originalPosition.top + ui.size.height;
        var currentH = container.outerHeight() + container.scrollTop();

        if (pos+20 >= currentH) {
            container.scrollTop(pos + 20 - container.outerHeight());
        }
        if (pos-20 <= container.scrollTop()) {
            container.scrollTop(pos-20);
        }
    }
```

this makes the page scroll but, then I get the problem:
[image]

1. That the handle no longer follow the mouse. And the longer I scroll the longer from the cursor the handle is. I've recreated this issue here based on TJ VanTolls fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/YwMXS/:

```js
$('#inner').resizable({
    containment: '#outer',
    handles: 'all'
});
```

```css
body { padding: 20px; }
p { line-height: 1.5; margin-bottom: 20px; }

#outer, #inner {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#outer {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#inner {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}
#content {
    height: 2000px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>
When scrolling during resize the handle does no longer follow the mouse.
To recreate: start resizing and during the resize scroll the parent.</p>

<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

So my  Question is, do you know a way to fix my first problem without causing the second or if there is a way to fix the second issue?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i know it's a bit late but here's what works for me, the issue is that your css is centering the element so you'll need to double the width and height of the resized elemnt to keep in sync with the mouse:

```
  resize: function (event, ui) {
                    var newWidth = ui.originalSize.width + ((ui.size.width - ui.originalSize.width) * 2);

                    //restrict min size if you want
                    if (newWidth < 50) {
                        newWidth = 50;
                    }
                    var newHeight = ui.originalSize.height + ((ui.size.height - ui.originalSize.height) * 2);

                    //restrict min size if you want
                    if (newHeight < 50) {
                        newHeight = 50;
                    }

                    //constrain this to the immediate parent
                    var parent = $(this).closest(".my-container");
                    if (parent.length) {
                        $(this).width(newWidth).position({
                            of: parent,
                            my: "center center",
                            at: "center center"
                        });
                        $(this).height(newHeight).position({
                            of: parent,
                            my: "center center",
                            at: "center center"
                        });
                    }
                }
```